# Machine learning to select features to create predictive model

Tags: modeling, feature-selection, prediction, keras

Sorry if this is a little confused!

I am experimenting Forex data using keras to attempt to find phenomena that predicts a rise or fall in a forex symbol's price. My dataset is millions of prices per minute per symbol with 50 or so technical indicators for each minute. So partly this is feature selection but I expect that within each feature there is a limit range in which the price is predictable.

I realise that in the vast majority of cases the forex price cannot be predicted from the data so simply feeding all the data into a neural network won't work. However, I want to find out if during particular phenomenon it can be predicted. For example, if x feature is above 70 for 3 minutes, and y feature is increasing (and feature a is.. and feature b is... etc) then this is predictive of a rise in forex price. At the moment, I am attempting a brute force approach by randomly selecting the criteria for the features, then finding the data that meets that criteria then feeding the data into a neural network. But it isn't proving very successful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? How would I begin to create a model that selects bands of the features that lead to a successful prediction?

Comment: I understand that you want to build a predictive model. But the question you ask is "Can anyone point me in the right direction please?" which is far too general to be answerable. Can you edit your question to ask specifically what it is that you want to know more about?

Comment: My problem isn't really with creating a predictive model. It is to create a model that creates the parameters of data selection so that it's possible to make a prediction. Sorry, I wish I could make it more specific. I guess I will have to find someone to discuss first to know exactly what I am looking for.  Maybe it isn't even possible.

Comment: Are you asking about [tag:feature-selection]?

Comment: Yes that is what I want. I will edit the question to include that. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, so would it be fair to say that your question is asking for a general description of the different approaches to feature selection? Because there are many feature selection methods, and it would be challenging to summarize them all in a peer-reviewed article, and not possible to answer in this forum. Perhaps you could do some research and come back with a specific question about feature selection after you've learned about some of the various methods that exist?

Comment: Thanks. Is feature selection what I am talking about though? Is isn't just features a and b predict x that I want to find but rather when a and b are within these ranges they can predict x (when they are in other ranges they can't). If I understand the article you linkd me to correctly, I am talking about sub-set selection. Is that right?